# Successfully deployed MVC 4 site runs but does not display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, web, iis-7.5, webmatrix

I succesffuly deployed an MVC 4 application to IIS Express on my development machine and everything runs fine. I can also successfully deploy to my production server, but when trying to access the deployed application in the production envioronment it can't be displayed.

Development tool: Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web.

Production server (all updates installed):
- Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- IIS 7.5
- MS .Net Framework 4.5
- ASP.Net MVC 4 with language pack
- Web Deploy 2.1 and Web Deploy 3.0
- Recommended configuration for IIS.

Furthermore, ASP.NET is registered with IIS for Framework\v4.0.30319 and Framwork64\v4.0.30319 and the application pool of the site is .Net Framework v4.0.30319. The IIS_IUSRS group has inherited permissions (Read & Execute, List Folder Contents and Read).

I have a production web server tied to the web via DynDNS, my site uses port 80.

What could be the cause for the site running but not displaying?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Additional info**: When I check the compatibility in WebMatrix of any site deployed to the production server I **always** get the result "Not available" for a Simple HTML-Page (the .Net-Framework-Version on the other hand always gives "Available").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that everything is ok, I had a DNS-Server error (wrong external server address).